# How to keep values equals to 0 with the function 'summarise' in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to summarise a large dataframe to analyse only a few variables in R. The df consists of several countries and the funding they allocate to different type of actors. I am using the functions "group_by %>% summarise" from the dplyr package to do so.

My problem is, if a country does not allocate any funding to one type of actors, the corresponding row does not appear. However, I would like to have that line appear, with values equals to 0. I did not find arguments that could do this in RDocumentation for the summarise function (I thought maybe na.rm = TRUE, but it did not change anything).

Here is an example of my data, with the result I have from summarise, and then what I would like it to look like.

My primary dataframe (data) looks something like this:

| Project | Year | Actor_name | Country | Actor_Type | Funding |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Proj_1 | 2019 | Actor_A | United Kingdom | University | 100 |
| Proj_1 | 2019 | Actor_B | Spain | Public administration | 0 |
| Proj_1 | 2019 | Actor_C | United Kingdom | Private company | 100 |
| Proj_2 | 2020 | Actor_A | United Kingdom | University | 200 |
| Proj_2 | 2020 | Actor_D | Spain | Private company | 0 |
| Proj_2 | 2020 | Actor_E | Spain | Private company | 50 |
| Proj_3 | 2018 | Actor_F | Spain | University | 100 |
| Proj_3 | 2018 | Actor_G | United Kingdom | University | 50 |

I run the following code to summarise this data:

```
df <- data[, c("Project", "Actor_name","Country", "Actor_Type", "Funding")] %>% group_by(Country, Actor_Type) %>% summarise(nb_proj = (n_distinct(Project)), nb_participant = (n_distinct(Actor_name)), Funding = sum(Funding))
```

Which gives me the following result:

df

| Country | Actor_Type | nb_proj | nb_participant | Funding |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Spain | Private company | 1 | 2 | 50 |
| Spain | Public administration | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Spain | University | 1 | 1 | 100 |
| United Kingdom | Private company | 1 | 1 | 100 |
| United Kingdom | University | 3 | 2 | 350 |

However, I would like to have the following result:

| Country | Actor_Type | nb_proj | nb_participant | Funding |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Spain | Private company | 1 | 2 | 50 |
| Spain | Public administration | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Spain | University | 1 | 1 | 100 |
| United Kingdom | Private company | 1 | 1 | 100 |
| **United Kingdom** | **Public administration** | **0** | **0** | **0** |
| United Kingdom | University | 3 | 2 | 350 |

Basically, I would like to have the information in the row in bold.

Does anyone know how I could do that? I tried with adding an na.rm = TRUE:

```
df <- data[, c("Project", "Actor_name","Country", "Actor_Type", "Funding")] %>% group_by(Country, Actor_Type, na.rm = TRUE) %>% summarise(nb_proj = (n_distinct(Project)), nb_participant = (n_distinct(Actor_name)), Funding = sum(Funding))
```

But it did not change the result.

Thank you!

Comment: Read about complete: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html